# How to reject a bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

Is it possible for a bounty-awardée to reject a bounty in order to prevent the decrease of the bounty-starter's "reputation"?

Comment: No; Meta.SE reference: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/168244)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Bounties are there to give questions additional *exposure* and are removed from the 'donors' reputation at the point they are set up. Even if the question involved does not gain any answers as a result, the bounty is *not returned to the donor*. The question will have been 'promoted' by the bounty (there is a dedicated bounty list which is *much* smaller than the full list of questions, or even of unanswered questions).

Comment: This seems to be the same for all SE forums.